# C# Check if items in checklistbox are un-checked?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to list all items in a directory which has been successful. I need to check if the item's status is "Unchecked", and if it is to give me the name of it in a variable.

TL;DR: If item is unchecked, write item in variable.

```
private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(e.Index) == true)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
                {
                    // If so, loop through all checked items and print results.  
                    string s = "";
                    for (int x = 0; x < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; x++)
                    {
                        if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[x] == 0)
                        {
                            s = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[x].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all unchecked items:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    List<String> items = new List<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
        {
            items.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        }
    }

    // ... do something with "items" ...
    foreach(String item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```